# accessing collection inside json object angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I am new to angular 
in the following controller i need to access the object store in my html. But it is not working. Any help

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';


    angular.module('app').controller('BookController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.book = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Harry Potter',
      author: 'J. K. Rowling',
      stores: [
     { id: 1, name: 'Barnes & Noble', quantity: 3 },
     { id: 2, name: 'Waterstones', quantity: 2 },
     { id: 3, name: 'Book Depository', quantity: 5 }
      ]
     };
    }]);
    });
```

```html
 <div ng-controller="BookController">
  
   
      {{book.stores}}
   </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Try this: `{{book.stores | json}}`

Comment: Should probably invoke the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first invoke your anonymous function first using `()` after the final closing bracket and before the final semi-colon so that the last line looks like this: `})();`.

You should define angular `module` first and then amend it with the angular component like `controller`, `service` , `factory`, `directive`, `filters`, etc.

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

then add `ng-app="app"` on your page.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BookController">
    {{book.stores}}
</div>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FFEPdEx9YjqQ6E8J9s6S?p=preview)

**Update**

If suppose you have multiple `store` inside the `stores` object, and you want to show them on the html, then for that you could `ng-repeat` directive. It will repeat each element on html

```
<div ng-repeat="s in book.stores">
   <span>{{s.name}}</span>
   <input type="text" ng-model="s.name" />
   <input type="numeric" ng-model="s.quantity" />
</div>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wxumCMfMjwDVgsbOzFWW?p=preview)

Comment: you could [add a repeater](http://plnkr.co/edit/ec0qiD90PKrFW7LeiG11?p=preview) to give it even more **power** (have a play in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ec0qiD90PKrFW7LeiG11?p=preview) in this comment to see the **power**) I wish "comment" started with a "p".

Comment: feel free to add it to your answer so that it's all available here :)

Comment: @lukkea I putted both the solution together..that will give more detailed view answer

Comment: The dependeny was defined in the app.js like   var app = angular.module('app', [
        // Angular modules 
        'ngAnimate',        // animations
        'ngRoute',          // routing
        'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)

        // Custom modules 
        'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner
        'common.bootstrap', // bootstrap dialog wrapper functions

        // 3rd Party Modules
        'ui.bootstrap'      // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)
    ]);
so it seemsthere was no need toinclud in the controller the []